# how can i embed a powerpoint slide into a webpage

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, powerpoint

is there any clean way of doing this that works in all browsers?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Convert it into a PDF or an image and put that in the webpage.

Edit: Oops, Mark H is totally right. This solution won't work in `lynx`. Your best bet for *all* browsers is to convert your slide into ASCII art.

Comment: So if you're trashing PDF, what's your alternative?

Comment: Just being anal about web standards. There are web standard solutions (ie, google docs/scribd). If you use PDF, there's no guarantee it will display in a browser as opposed to opening an external PDF reader. If that's the case, why bother trying to make it web-compatible?

Comment: Since when is Google Docs a "standard"? And how is it better than PDF? (In each case, you have to navigate to either another webpage or a PDF reader.) As for scribd, it's kind of annoying, especially for something simple like a single PowerPoint slide. (scribd's HTML5 stuff is better, but its iPaper solution wasn't that amazing. Also, scribd is hardly a "standard" either. (Doesn't iPaper require Flash, too?) I also said "or an image", since using a JPEG or PNG *would* be a standard way that would work in all browsers save for text-only browsers.

Comment: @mipadi - how would i then embed pdf inside of website ?

Comment: You can link to it, you can't embed it per se. If you want to embed it, convert the slide to an image and embed that.

Comment: No Lynx?  Thats a deal breaker.  Although I agree with Mark's point.  The question did say all browsers.

Comment: I didn't say google docs was a standard. I meant it is based entirely on web standards (defined by w3c). Web browsers are made to comply with those standards, and any extras are bloat as far as I'm concerned. You can already embed office into most browsers, so why even bother converting if you're going to take that route?

Anyway, since you mention images, I'll remove the -ve. 

@ooo I'd recommend the image method, and use some jQuery (or YUI/Extjs etc) based technique to run the presentation. Some techniques here: http://tutzone.net/2010/02/10-best-jquery-gallery-slideshow-techniques.html

Answer (score 4):

if your web app is on the internet, you can use dedicated ppt hosting services ([SlideShare](http://www.slideshare.net/), etc.), that will manage this problem for you.

Theses services often use the Adobe flash technology that is availible (by plugins) on most browsers.

Comment: No solution can strickly  "works in all browsers"... since no solution can show a ppt in Lynx (for example). Now, Flash (and PDF) can be printed on *most* browers (and not *all* browsers), which is a good compromise.